# 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception, reference

I'm getting the following error in a .Net c# MVC application, targetting the .Net Framework Version 4.5:

`The type 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.`

I have added the reference in the project, and I have even edited the web.config to include a reference to the assembly under:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find any explanation why the Exception is happening.  Has anyone had the same exception?

Comment: Your error says a Version=2.0.0.0 and your target framework is .Net 4.5, may be that's where the conflict is; to the dll version you have referenced..

Comment: Are you suggesting that I referenced the version 2 framework instead of the latest version? Let's give it a go...

Comment: No luck... still have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider checking the machine.config and other configuration files.  In the above case, a corrupted machine.config was the problem.